# Почему 1%2 ===1 JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как работает оператор "Остаток от деления".

```
4%2===0   // это ясно
5%2===1   // это тоже понятно
```

но что насчет того, что левый операнд меньше?

Comment: Такие правила деления с остатком

Comment: Да но как это понимать ?

Comment: Ноль целых и один в остатке

Comment: Нв этот вопрос отвечают в начальных классах общеобразовательной школы.

Comment: @Александр интересно, расскажите подробнее

Comment: http://math-prosto.ru/?page=pages/division_with_remainder/division_with_remainder.php

Answer (score 2):

Если разделить 1 на 2 с остатком, получится 0 (остаток 1). Ноль раз по два и один в остатке.